# How use title data in datatable json?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

I want the table title and table body use url to read data.

such as  `"language": {url:'https://cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.25/i18n/English.json'},`

```
$(document).ready(function () {


 $('#example').DataTable({ 

  "language": {url:'https://cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.25/i18n/English.json'},

  lengthMenu: [25, 50, 75, 100],


  data: {url:'/dataSet.json'},
  columns: {url:'/columns.json'}
  });
  
});
```

---

```js
$(document).ready(function () {


 var dataSet = [
{"name":"name1","name2":"name2"},
{"name":"name1","name2":"name2"},
];

$('#example').DataTable({ 
 "language": {url:'https://cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.25/i18n/English.json'},

  lengthMenu: [25, 50, 75, 100],
 

  data: dataSet,
  columns: [

{ title:"Title1",data: "name" },
{ title:"Title2",data: "name2" }

  
  ]
  
 });
  
});
```

```css
 tfoot {

  display: table-header-group;
}
 }
```

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>

<link href="https://nightly.datatables.net/css/jquery.dataTables.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="https://nightly.datatables.net/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
<!-- Select2 plugin -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/css/select2.min.css">
<!-- Select2 plugin -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>DataTables - JS Bin</title>

  </head>
  <body>

<div class="container">
 <table id="example" width="100%"></table>

 </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

How can do that?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Use the DataTables [`ajax`](https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/ajax) option and pass in all the data you need as JSON. Your JSON can contain two objects - one containing an array of column headings, the other containing the table's data.

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64242502/jquery-datatable-add-dynamic-columns) is an example (in this case, the columns are extracted from the JSON table data). Or, if you prefer to use jQuery for your ajax call, there is an example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28140671/datatables-with-dynamic-columns).

Comment: @andrewjames  Thank you for your guidance. Is ajax just for table body ? If I want table title and table body. How can do that?

Comment: I tried to address that with my comment "_Your JSON can contain two objects - one containing an array of column headings, the other containing the table's data_" and the related links. Did I miss the point of your question? (No, ajax is not just for the body.)

Comment: @andrewjames Thank you. I tried ajax, but it is not working.                                                       
 Code link : http://live.datatables.net/kisafixu/6/edit                                                                          Txt link : https://ffirsttname.github.io/bootstrap-sortable-demo/title_en.txt

Comment: I added an example, to see if that is clearer than the linked examples. Is this what you mean by "table title"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example using a jQuery `ajax` approach:

Assume we have a URL which returns the following JSON:

```js
{
  "responseData": {
    "headings": [
      {
        "title": "Name",
        "data": "name"
      },
      {
        "title": "Position",
        "data": "position"
      },
      {
        "title": "Salary",
        "data": "salary"
      },
      {
        "title": "Start Date",
        "data": "start_date"
      },
      {
        "title": "Office",
        "data": "office"
      },
      {
        "title": "Age",
        "data": "age"
      }
    ],
    "body": [
      {
        "name": "Tiger Nixon",
        "position": "System Architect",
        "salary": "$320,800",
        "start_date": "2011/04/25",
        "office": "Edinburgh",
        "age": "23"
      },
      {
        "name": "Lael Greer",
        "position": "Systems Administrator",
        "salary": "$103,500",
        "start_date": "2009/02/27",
        "office": "London",
        "age": "24"
      },
      {
        "name": "Jonas Alexander",
        "position": "Developer",
        "salary": "$86,500",
        "start_date": "2010/07/14",
        "office": "San Francisco",
        "age": "54"
      },
      {
        "name": "Shad Decker",
        "position": "Regional Director",
        "salary": "$183,000",
        "start_date": "2008/11/13",
        "office": "Edinburgh",
        "age": "43"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

The overall structure can be summarized as this:

```js
{
  "responseData": {
    "headings": [ { ... }, { ... }, ... ],
    "body": [ { ... }, { ... }, ... ]
  }
}
```

Now we have the data needed for all our data rows in one section of the JSON, and the titles (column headings) in another section.

The DataTable can be fed this data from a jQuery `ajax` call:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $.ajax({
      url: "YOUR_URL_GOES_HERE",
    method: "POST",
    success: function(json) {
      initializeDataTable(json);
    }
  });

  function initializeDataTable(json) {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
      "data": json.responseData.body,
      "columns": json.responseData.headings
    } );
  }

} );
```

And the HTML table is simply this:

```
<table id="example" class="display" style="width:100%"></table>
```

So, now there are no specific column names anywhere in the HTML or the DataTable definition. All that data is provided by the JSON.

You can add more data to the JSON, to control other aspects of the DataTable - for example , the initial sort order, and so on.

Comment: Thank you for your guidance. Finally i try the `method: "POST"` to change `method: "GET"`, it working. Thank you so much.